# Error, #1054 la columna en field list es desconocida

Tags: sql

Buenas me esta dando este error al subirlo a phpmyadmin, #1054 la columna cod_asignatura en field list es desconocida.

tabla asignatura:

```
/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ASIGNATURA;*/
Create table IF NOT EXISTS ASIGNATURA(
COD_ASIGNATURA INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CODIGO_PENSUM VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
DESCRIPCION_ASIGNATURA VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
UC_ASIGNATURA INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
HT TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
HP TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
HL TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
PERIODO_PENSUM INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (COD_ASIGNATURA, CODIGO_PENSUM)
);
```

y aquí estoy insertando los campos:

```
 INSERT INTO ASIGNATURA (COD_ASIGNATURA, CODIGO_PENSUM, 
 DESCRIPCION_ASIGNATURA, UC_ASIGNATURA, HT, HP, HL, PERIODO_PENSUM) VALUES
 (1, 'MAT-21213', 'MATEMATICA I', 5, '03:00:00', '01:30:00', '00:00:00', 1),
 (2, 'MAT-21225', 'MATEMATICA II', 5, '03:00:00','01:30:00','00:00:00', 2),
 (3, 'MAT-21235', 'MATEMATICA III', 5, '03:00:00','01:30:00','00:00:00', 3),
 (4, 'MAT-31214', 'CALCULO NUMERICO', 4, '02:15:00', '02:15:00', '00:00:00', 
 4);
```

Comment: Lo intente de ambas maneras colocándole el valor y no haciéndolo, me da el mismo error en la columna de COD_ASIGNATURA.

Comment: Por favor revisa este ejemplo, aquí [he replicado el ejercicio](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1364175809323995056e5a7797767ee)

Comment: no comprendo lo que quiere hacer, no percibo un cambio entre lo que me muestra y tenemos mas que el espaciado en el insert y el select y no me funciono tampoco, así que no estoy muy claro que quiere que revise.

Comment: que tu código es funcional, mencionas hacer esto desde phpmyadmin, trata desde la terminal y cuéntanos que resultó pues como te digo he usado tu ejemplo y funciona

Comment: ya lo hice y si corrió, ese es un fragmento de una base de datos, al intentar importarla me da ese error en este lugar y si lo pruebo con todo el código también me da el mismo error pero al comienzo sale el mensaje que dice que esta desactivada porque es muy largo.

Comment: Quita *cod_asignatura* del la lista de campos y de los valores en el insert. *cod_asignatura* es autonumérico y el gestor de BD lo genera para cada registro que insertas.